Firebase Console showing no data for android app
I have added Firebase analytics to my app where I log the events using analytics library. The code for same is
analytics().logEvent('channel_opened');

But the problem is that the app does not shows up any data on Firebase Console. This works perfectly for iOS, but the issue is for Android only. I have done all the changes required for events to show up. Also, Firebase is setup correctly because I use Firebase messaging to send notifications which works correctly.

It may take up to 24 hours to appear in the console. You can use DebugView to see real-time events.

@VivekPratapSingh its more than a week I have added app.
